# Releasing multiple sub directories of a single repo that can be imported using common python import base path

Tags: python, python-import, pypi, python-packaging

**Problem:**

I am trying to create a large repo in Github with multiple subdirectory releases into Pypi. I am looking to managing my releases and imports similar to how Azure does.

**Example:**

To install Azure key vault and Azure Resource management , the following commands can be run.

```
pip install azure-keyvault-secrets
pip install azure-mgmt-resource
```

These are treated as two different pypi releases but when importing the two libraries into a python script, they share the same base path (`azure`). For e.g. ,

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
```

**What I have done so far:**

Not much besides lots of searching online for the solution. I am unsure if this feature is a specific feature of python or github. I am unable to to find the exact feature name so I am unsure where to start. Most of my google search leads to `git submodules` which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: "*…share the same base path…*" They're called [namespace packages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+namespace+packages).

Comment: Yes, as already said, they are "*namespace packages*", that is the key word you should look up. I will also add [this guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/), make sure to use the "*[**native** namespace packages technique](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages)*".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+native+namespace+packages